# My username is associated with another .onmicrosoft.com account when I log in to Azure - How do I change it?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to sign in to Azure with my Company Given user account, I get the following message:

"We were unable to find any Azure subscriptions where you are a service administrator or co-administrator.

You are signed as username in the directory random_name.onmicrosoft.com."

I'd like my username associated with another yourcompanyname.onmicrosoft.com that others in my company are using.  Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is a question for StackOverflow, or any StackExchange network site, to be honest.  You'd probably need to contact your IT department within your company to validate you're even setup, or Azure support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. There may or may not be another Stack Exchange site where it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the account you're using to login to the portal with is associated with the correct active directory that you want to use, and that you have permissions in the subscription you want to access as well.  If you're using a Microsoft account, then you will need to ask whoever controls the directory for your company account to add your account to the directory - or get them to create you a user in the directory with the name *yourusername*@*yourcompanyname*.onmicrosoft.com, and login with that instead.

Comment: Russell, thank you very much for your response!  How do I connect my PowerBI Pro subscription I have from BizSpark to my yourusername@yourcompanyname.onmicrosoft.com given now that it's connected to a "random_name.onmicrosoft.com"?  I really appreciate the help especially since I'm a newbie with all of these MS subscriptions.

Comment: No idea where the random name domain has come from - you should be able to use a Microsoft account or your company's .onmicrosoft.com (azure ad account) across any subscription.  Just make sure the email account you want to use is added to the directories associated with the subscription.  If the subscription has a default directory that is the random one and you don't want it, edit the directories for the subscription and change it